# pytorch int32 to int64 conversion

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to convert a simple image mask to `int64`

```py
image = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]], dtype='int32')

transform = Compose([
    torch.from_numpy, 
    ConvertImageDtype(torch.int64)
])
```

However, `transform(image)` yields

```
tensor([[ 4294967296,  8589934592],
        [12884901888, 17179869184]])
```

Is there something wrong, or am I fundamentally misunderstanding something about how the conversion should work?

Answer (score 2):

If you skip torch's conversion, the image is transformed correctly.

```
image = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]], dtype='int64')

transform = Compose([
    torch.from_numpy
])
transform(image)
# tensor([[1, 2],
#        [3, 4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late but just in case…

The `ConvertImageDtype` docstring states:

> Convert a tensor image to the given dtype and **scale the values accordingly**

In the source code, we can see this function calls a `F.convert_image_dtype` function which then calls a `F_t.convert_image_dtype` function where we can understand how the scaling is done:

```py
...
input_max = _max_value(image.dtype)
...
output_max = _max_value(dtype)
...
factor = int((output_max + 1) // (input_max + 1))
...
return image * factor
```

For the int32 representation `input_max == 2147483647 == 2**(32-1) -1`.
For the int64 representation `output_max == 9223372036854775807 == 2**(64-1) -1`.

(The `-1` in `32-1` and `64-1` is because one byte is used for the sign.
The final `-1`… I don't know, but we see that `factor` uses a `+1` to "correct" it.)

So we get `factor == 4294967296` which is used to scale your image…

Now, in the source code we can also see:

```py
    if image.is_floating_point():
        ...
        # float to int  <= actually written in the code
        ...
    else:
        ...
        # int to float  <= actually written in the code
        ...
```

So basically the code assumes one won't try anything except "float to int" and "int to float" conversion, but does not strictly check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert the tensors with the `.to()` method:

```py
tensor_with_dtype_int64 = tensor_with_dtype_int32.to(torch.int64)
```